# What OS does heroku cedar run?

Tags: heroku

I had though cedar was running on Ubuntu 10.04, but when checking it seems this is not the case:

```
heroku run python
from platform import platform
platform()
'Linux-3.8.11-ec2-x86_64-with-debian-squeeze-sid'
```

A binary I previously compiled on 10.04 and ran happily on heroku is now segfaulting, so I'd like to work out what stack to compile against.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's Ubuntu 10.04, here's the output from `heroku run bash`

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on their [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack), it is running Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Yes, I should have explicitly said that I suspect the docs are wrong. Can anyone confirm from observing a dyno or direct knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

They are now running Ubuntu 14.04 :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#cedar

Answer (score 0):

In one line (based on John Beynon's answer ):

```
heroku run  "lsb_release -a"
```

Response:

...
   Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS